# Nestjs multi database connections with mongoose

Tags: database, mongoose, nestjs

I've got a database that has accounts (accounts, users, roles, permissions, ...) and flows and processes related to the accounts. We are trying to, if the client wishes, have a different database just for the client data, in this case flows and processes.

If the account data has a specific mongo uri it should use that for the flows, otherwise it should use the normal connection.

We have a guard to authenticate the users and get his account and would like to connect to the proper database after the guard being called BUT the MongooseService is called before the guard since it's in the app.module.ts and so the uri information is empty:

```
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      connectionName: 'customer',
      useClass: MongooseService,
    }),
```

The MongooseService has:

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class MongooseService implements MongooseOptionsFactory {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: IRequest) {}

  createMongooseOptions(): MongooseModuleOptions {
    console.log(
      'MongooseService',
      this.request.date,
      this.request.url,
      this.request.user,
    );
    if (this.request.user.uri) {
      return {
        uri: this.request.user.url,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      };
    } else {
      return { uri: // get uri from .env };
    }
  }
}
```

Our guard has this:

```
...
      // validate token
      const token = this.getToken(request);
      const jwtData = this.jwtService.verify<IJwtData>(token);
...
      let user = await this.teamService.findOne(jwtData.id);
      request.user = user;
...
```

Is there anyway of using this strategy, using connection names (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#multiple-databases) or since we need data from the database we need to use a different approach?

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom provider for **MongooseService** and `inject` into your **Guard** this way will make you can instantiate the `MongooseService` after the **Guard** has been called and the user data will be available

```
import { Provider } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseService } from './mongoose.service';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

export const MongooseProvider: Provider = {
  provide: MongooseService,
  useFactory: (req: IRequest) => {
    console.log(
      'MongooseService',
      req.date,
      req.url,
      req.user,
    );
    if (req.user.uri) {
      return {
        uri: req.user.url,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      };
    } else {
      return { uri: ConfigService.get("MY_ENV_URL"}; // get uri from .env
    }
  },
  inject: [REQUEST],
};
```

Comment: What should I inject in the guard? The Service or the Provider?
How can I do so?

Comment: injects the MongooseService when the request object is available:

Comment: Can you please explain how to I do that?
Do I need to change the app.modele.ts or MongooseService?
Thanks